# How to add elements to multidimensional arrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

If I create a class such as

```
public class record{
  int index;
  String name;
}
```

and then an ArrayList
    ArrayList<.record> members = new ArrayList<.record>();

How do I add individual elements?
I thought there would be something like
    members[x].index.add(someintegervalue);
    members[x].name.add(somestringvalue);

and then a similar command to set new values if I wanted to change existing values.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: This question has been answered, however it led to another problem. How to pass an  ArrayList pointer to a function().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<record> members = new ArrayList<record>(); 

//to add a member 
member obMember = new member();
obMember.index = 0;
obMember.name="name";

members.add(obMember);

//to update get child of position cast it and update

member newMember  = (menber)members.get(position);
newMember.name="newName";
member.set(location, newMember);
```

Comment: Thanks Shailendra, all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
public class Record{
  public int index;
  public String name;
}
```

---

```
Record myRecord = new Record();
myRecord.index = someintegervalue;
myRecord.name = somestringvalue;
```

then add it to arraylist by

```
members.add(myRecord);   or   members.add(x , myRecord );
```

add adding it to x potion the you can get

```
Record record = members.get(x);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be >> members.add(x, myRecord);